# DNS Server not forwarding requests

Tags: domain-name-system, voip

I have been working on setting up some VOIP phones for our provider.  The phones connect to their provisioning server in order to download the configuration.

If I leave the phone as DHCP, it gets our internal DNS server, which has forwarders set up to Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

But if the phone gets the IP from the DHCP server, it cannot resolve the domain name domain.jive.com.  But if I statically set the IP and DNS servers, only changing the DNS server to Google's, it is able to pull it's configuration.

I also have no problem getting to domain.jive.com from my PC which is on the same subnet with the same default gateway and internal DNS servers.

Any ideas on what could be blocking this phone from resolving the domain name?

Comment: Can you confirm the phones setting up their dns properly (if there is any network information screen or anything similar)? can you execute any command on the phones if there is any busybox?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between `leave the phone as DHCP` and `the phone gets the IP from the DHCP`? Also, which DHCP server are you using?

Comment: Yes I can go through the log and see that it is getting our internal DNS server correctly.  It seems to be something specifically with the DNS server, because I am able to give it a different internal DNS server and it resolves the hostname fine.

But I can also ping the domain directly from that DNS server.